# WindowsAuthentication on ASPNET MVC 3 not working (IsAuthenticated always false)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication

I'm trying to enable Windows authentication (setting windows mode on authentication) on a huge legacy ASPNET MVC 3 Application, but it isn't working and I can't find why; the Request.IsAuthenticated is always false. The app is very huge and has a lot of personalization with its own authentication and authorization system, but it uses the standard mechanisms of ASPNETMVC to override them (OnAuthorize). I've tried with empty controllers without "personalization" but it doesn't work neither.

I don't know how to start to write here all configuration so, I'm expecting for a genius who could point me to what is wrong...

I've tried too on a sampe new ASPNETMVC3 (from VS2010 templates) and it works fine; I would try to set every thing of my app on this one slowly to try to reproduce if I didn't found any solution before.

--- UPDATE ---

I've copied the web.config and global.asax of template project and it's not working yet. I've added the event WindowsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate on both projects and only enters on the demo project. I can't undersand how, where or why the ASPNET flow is broken.

Comment: What web-browser are you using? Not all browsers support Windows Authentication, and even then "Windows Authentication" in IIS + ASP.NET is a byword for Kerberos and NTLM authentication, which only work in a subset of circumstances (**and they especially don't work over the Internet**, which is why OIDC SSO is gaining popularity)

Comment: Also, why are you using ASP.NET MVC 3.0 and VS2010 anyway?

Comment: @Dai It's the customer requirement, and it's installed on its intranet environment. It's not a browser problem, because as it's working on a template ASPNETMVC app. About your question, it's a hughe legacy app and it isn't easy to migrate to latest technologies, we've migrated to VS2017 yet, but the sample app was on 2010 because 2017 has not the template. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If it's working as-intended in the stock template project then that's a good starting point. I recommend comparing the `web.config` files and also check for any `HttpModule` entries that are different.

Comment: you need to turnon feature on windows depending on your operating system. look for the settings as per your OS from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication/